# Connect a single LED to a reversable circuit?

Tags: led, reverse-polarity

I have a need to install a single small LED that will illuminate whenever a circuit is active. The circuit controls a small motor, and reverses polarity depending on which way the motor is operating. The motor has only two wires going to it, which is either +/- to turn one way or -/+ to turn the other. This is a 14V circuit.

My initial thought was to try to use a dual-polarity LED, but apparently that only exists in my imagination as far as I can tell by searching. Using a dual-color LED is a possibility also, but I still have no clue the correct way to wire it up.

Comment: You know what a bridge rectifier is, right?

Comment: Two LEDs in parallel with opposite polarity will be OK since the most LEDs can hold 5v reversed polarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a bipolar LED or two LEDs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foHfRL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[Here](https://www.kingbrightusa.com/images/catalog/SPEC/WP57SURKSURKD.pdf) is an example part that has two LED dies of the same color (red) in one package.

[image]

Perhaps more common are parts with two colors (such as red and green) in the same package. That would allow you to indicate direction. Or you could use two individual LEDs.

A resistor in the 2kΩ range would conduct about 5mA which will provide adequate brightness with most modern LEDs.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple is this: The diodes will prevent the current from flowing in the wrong direction. 10k resistor should be enough for indicator LED and the high resistance will further protect the LED from reverse current.

You can also use a bridge rectifier made of 4 diodes if high current is needed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZIdwJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What's the purpose of D1 and D2 here? It seems like the circuit would do pretty much the same thing without them.

Comment: @TannerSwett LEDs are sensitive to reverse bias. Many data sheets state maximum reverse voltage is 5V. Without the diode, there will be a lot more than 5V in reverse over the LED if supply wires are 14V. This is only one way of using the diode for that, putting it in series, but other methods such as putting the diode in anti-parallel.

Answer (score 0):

A dual color LED is just two anti-parallel LEDs, you connect them the same as with a single LED, but which one lights will depend on the polarity of the applied voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBENFU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the polarity is as shown, the Red LED will light, if the polarity is reversed the Green LED will light.

There will be a slight difference in current due to the different colors having different voltage drops but it shouldn't be a problem. And reverse polarity shouldn't be a problem as the forward voltage of each LED limits the reverse voltage of the other.

An added feature is that you not only have an indicator of when the motor is on, but an indicator of the direction as well.